# Vega Align axes labels with ticks

Tags: vega-lite, vega

For some reason I have to use band scale to make the chart and I find out "tickCount" not working with band scale. And my chart ends like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7klj.png)
x-axis is somewhat messy with all the ticks showing. Can vega change tick numbers in band scale or align ticks with labels?

I tried to add anthor time scale axis, but the point and the ticks cannot match, like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3q92.png)
So I think it's better if there is anyway that vega support change tick numbers with band scale

Comment: Share a spec and describe your desired result